# Bash if statement produces different result with exclamation mark in different positions

Tags: bash

My first question is **why putting `!` in the front of if statement** fails to produce syntax error when `status` is not double quoted. That is how is `[ ! $x = "string" ]` different from 
`[ $x != "string" ]`?

My script is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

status=" "

# Comparison 1: without error
echo "-----Comparison 1-----"
if [ ! $status = "success" ]
then echo 'Error: status was not success but: ' $status
else
  echo "The status is success."
fi
echo "-----Comparison 2-----"
# Comparison 2: with error message but still shows success
if [ $status != "success" ]
then echo 'Error: status was not success but: ' $status
else
  echo "The status is success."
fi
echo "-----Comparison 3-----"
# Comparison 3: Correct result after quoting status
if [ ! "$status" == "success" ]
then echo 'Error: status was not success but: ' $status
else
  echo "The status is success."
fi
echo "-----Comparison 4-----"
# Comparison 4: Correct result after quoting status
if [ "$status" != "success" ]
then echo 'Error: status was not success but: ' $status
else
  echo "The status is success."
fi
```

The output is

```
-----Comparison 1-----
The status is success.
-----Comparison 2-----
./test2.sh: line 14: [: !=: unary operator expected
The status is success.
-----Comparison 3-----
Error: status was not success but:
-----Comparison 4-----
Error: status was not success but:
```

Additional questions

- Why does it produce `"The status is success."` in `Comparison 2` after a syntax error? How would a syntax error in an if statement affects the evaluated result of such if statement?

p.s. I know we need `""` around `$status` to make output right.

Comment: Use `[[ .. ]]` instead of `[ .. ]`

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `$status`. Without the quotes, your first comparison is

```
if [ ! = "success" ]
```

which will fail because `!` and `success` are not equal strings.

Your second one results in a syntactically invalid expression for `[`:

```
if [ != "success" ]
```

The syntax error you see in condition 2 isn't a *shell* syntax error, but a *condition* syntax error raised by the `[` command. The command itself runs fine, but exits with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Why in the first scenario, it still produces `success`?

Comment: Because success means the condition did not hold, and `! = success` is indeed false. `!` isn't an operator in this context; it's just the left-hand operand of the `=` operator.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.